# How do I check for a tag's existence in a post in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

Quick question about Wordpress PHP: 
I am writing a theme and I want to display (on the main index page) one icon if my post has one tag, and another if it has the other.

I wrote something like

```
<?php has_tag('pc') { ?><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/pc-icon.gif"><?php }; ?>
<?php has_tag('mb') { ?><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/mb-icon.gif"><?php }; ?>
```

But it gives me an error. Can anybody help?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for that button...don't see it anywhere. I'm new here. How do I do that, exactly? I can't find anything that says "Mark as accepted."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if(has_tag('pc')) { ?><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/pc-icon.gif"><?php }; ?>
<?php if(has_tag('mb')) { ?><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/mb-icon.gif"><?php }; ?>
```

You're missing the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php if(has_tag('pc')) { ?><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/pc-icon.gif"><?php }; ?>
<?php if(has_tag('mb')) { ?><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/mb-icon.gif"><?php }; ?>
```

Comment: You guys are AWESOME! Thanks for getting back to me so quick. It works perfectly.